# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database ... does not exist

Tags: spring, postgresql, maven, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

Can someone explaining why I am receiving this error when I run 'mvn test' at the root of my project?
It is a Spring JPA application.
Database configuration is in the application.properties file in the test/resources folder. It is specified in standard JDBC URL format:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wds_fin
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

There are three databases under the schema - 'postgres', 'amigoscode' and 'wds_fin'.
All three belong to user 'postgres'.

I can connect to the server as a connection and see all three databases in both the pgAdmin tool and in
IntelliJ DB browser. Using the user 'postgress' and password 'password'.

If I change the Spring JPA properties file URL suffix to /postgres, the stack trace does not appear as it seems to connect to that database fine.
But for the other 2 it throws the exception.

This is the problem with Spring - its abstractions mean it is difficult to debug when something is wrong.
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

UPDATE:

Hi

Ok, sorry I misused the term schema.
I should have said server.

The pgAdmin view of the server connection is this:

[pgAdmin server connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YA85.jpg)

As you can see it contains the databases ‘amigoscode’, ‘postgres’ and ‘wds_fin’.
Each of these databases have the user owner postgres which has full privileges.

The connection details for the 'PostgreSQL11' server are:

```
Host name/address : localhost
Port: 5432
Maintenance database: postgres
Username: postgres
```

I have configured the application.properties file in my Spring Data JPA as follows:

```
spring.application.name=cryptoManager
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wds_fin
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

The datasource URL is the same as the PgAdmin PostgresSQL11 server connection and the wds_fin DB is specified.

When I run ‘mvn test’ at the root of the project the test suite runs but a stack trace is output:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "wds_fin" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2825)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.(QueryExecutorImpl.java:175)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:313)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:263)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)

Spring JPA is obviously doing its stuff in the background and attempting a connection as specified in the properties file.

If I change the spring.datasource.url property to :

jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

I no longer get the stack trace. So it seems to connect to the right server but can only access the ‘postgres’ database.

I have checked the properties for each of the databases and they are the same.
The only distinction I can see is that postgres is the ‘maintenance database’ of the server.

Many Thanks

Comment: 1) This `There are three databases under the schema - 'postgres', 'amigoscode' and 'wds_fin'.` is incorrect, schemas exist as namespaces in a database not the other way around. 2) Add the complete error message, **at text**, to your question text. 3) What does the Postgres show when you make the connection. Again add as text to the question. 4) Not sure what this `Changed URL in properties file to reference postgres table ...` means? Not aware of postgres table. Add the URL as update  to question.

Comment: What is in the database server's log file?  Maybe you are connecting to the wrong server, which might then have different databases, in which case the error message would be doing the log file of that different server.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have added an update to my original post so hopefully it is clearer. Many thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: 1) Is the Spring application on the same machine as the database server? 2) Using `psql` on the database server machine what happens when you do `psql -h localhost -d wds_fin -U postgres`?

Comment: They're on the same machine. Well, that gives me the message the database does not exist. If I use -d postgres it connects to that. I'm a bit confused by this as they are definitely there in the PgAdmin localhost server connection. Could I be missing some other configuration?

Comment: Actually, I think I am connecting to a different server. I've got myself in a knot my end. When logging into  'psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres', I can see this contains databases 'postgres' and 'student'. If I specify either of these in the jdbc URL property Spring JPA connects ok, with no exception. This is a different connection to the one with the wds_fin table. I don't understand at present, as post 5432 is default for postgres localhost connections - so I don't see how the CLI connection is different to the one in PgAdmin.

Comment: 1) Try with `psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -p 5432`.  2) What OS is the Postgres server running on? Use whatever process monitor you have available and see how many instances of Postgres you have running? 3) From here [libpq env variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) do you have `PGPORT` set?

Comment: My fault. It's because I'm running the mvn command in Windows Subsystem for Linux. I should have mentioned it in the question. It had a separate version of postgres running within the Linux environment which was the one I connected to when running the psql command . If I run the same tests from the Windows command prompt Spring JPA can find the database. I haven't quite got my head around processes running in WSL environment - they are of course completely separate to any Windows processes and any apps invoked from WSL will run in that context. Thanks for your help.